# Is there a minute picker available in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, plugins, picker, minute

I want a minute picker in jQuery without date and hours. Just minutes only from 0 to 60.
Is there any available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not special plugin just for minutes.

You can use and slider or range picker, that's logic you have just one number.

like these:

https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asRange

https://github.com/ghusse/jQRangeSlider